# $this->Session->destroy() this line is not working in cakephp 2.5

Tags: session, cakephp-2.5

I am new in cakephp. I use 2.5 version. I have problem in logout function. The code

```
$this->Session->destroy();
```

Is not working in my code if I hit the back button after logout the session then the welcome page appears. After refresh the welcome page then the session will destroy..this is my problem session.

```
 public function logout(){

  $this->Session->delete('username'); 
  if( $this->Session->destroy()) {
 echo $this->Session->setFlash("Congrats, you have successfully logged Out");
    $this->redirect('/users/login');
  }else{
 echo $this->Session->setFlash("you failed in log Out");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Auth you need to simply call Auth logout function. i.e

```
public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

or otherwise you can destroy both session or cookies.

```
public function logout(){
    $this->Session->destroy();
    $this->Cookie->destroy();
    $this->Session->setFlash('Congrats, you have successfully logged Out.');
    return $this->redirect('/users/login');
}
```